# Timeout Error PubSubHealthIndicator on springboot app

Tags: java

I'm working in a project which will use PUB/SUB. When I trying to start my springboot App, I received a TimeoutException as shown below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Validation of health indicator failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.validationFailed(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.validateHealthCheck(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:106)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.createIndicator(PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.createIndicator(PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.AbstractCompositeHealthContributorConfiguration.createContributor(AbstractCompositeHealthContributorConfiguration.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.pubSubHealthContributor(PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.pullMessage(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.health.PubSubHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(PubSubHealthIndicator.java:122)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I'm using Google SDK to set my credentials and project. As well as my application.yml:

```
gcp:
  project-id: ${PROJECT_ID}
  pubsub:
    topics:
      quotesOutputChannel: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/topics/my-topic
    subscriptions:
      quotesInputChannel: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/subscriptions/my-sub
```

It happens when I start springboot app.

How can I solve this? I've tried to set pub sub health false on my application.yml and it didn't work as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible for you to provide some more information on how to reproduce this error? If you need help on how to do that, take a look at the help page on [mre]s. Also, some people overuse Stack Overflow tags, but here I think tags might be being underused. Are there any tags for the technologies you are using that you haven't listed? You can search for tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: Hey, thanks you. I've made an update on my question. Thanks.